# Why ServiceInstaller is not available in my "WPF App(.NET Framework)" projetct?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-services, service-installer

I would like to install and uninstall a windows service programmably, But i can not use [ServiceInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) in my "WPF App(.NET Framework)" project.

[image]

[image]

Did i miss some references?

Comment: Do you control the source of the service? If you do then i suggest using topshelf. Your service exe is then a cosole app which has built in install and uninstall you could use.

Comment: Yes, but it is a Worker Service project

Comment: Topshelf is for easily developed and installed windows services. Read up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a project that targets the .NET Framework, you should add a reference to `System.ServiceProcess` under Project->Add Reference->Assemblies->Framework.

The `ServiceInstaller` class is not available in .NET Core or .NET 5.